# FileStream.Write doesn't write anything

Tags: c#, filestream

I've written the following code:

```
public static class PLog
{
    private static FileStream logFileStream;
    private static string logFilePath;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        logFilePath = PSettings.IO.dirLogs + "log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy_HHmmss") + ".txt";

        if (!Directory.Exists(PSettings.IO.dirLogs)) Directory.CreateDirectory(PSettings.IO.dirLogs);

        logFileStream = new FileStream(logFilePath, FileMode.Create);
    }

    public static void WriteLine(string text)
    {
        byte[] textArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm:ss") + "] " + text + "\n");

        logFileStream.Write(textArray, 0, textArray.Length);
    }

    public static void Close()
    {
        logFileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

But when I call it like this, it doesn't write anything to the file:

```
PLog.Initialize();
PLog.WriteLine("test");
PLog.Close();
```

The file was created but it had the size of 0 bytes.

Comment: have u called the Close(); method too?

Comment: If you question has been solved then please Mark the anwser that solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FileStream` implements `IDisposable`.

It is rarely a good idea to use it in a *static* context like you show in your code because it is hard to really ensure that IDisposable.Dispose() gets called to properly clean up the stream.

If you can, use `FileStream` with the *using* keyword to ensure that `Dispose()` is called

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(logFilePath, FileMode.Create))
{
   // Do stuff with fs
}
```

If you must keep your current structure, check that `Close()` *really* is called (and you're not e.g. getting an Exception that prevents it from being called).

**UPDATE**

Regarding your comment to the other answer:

Append `Environment.Newline` to the end of your string before you write it out.

Alternatively, you can use a [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx), which exposes a `WriteLine()` method.

Comment: Thank you very much, but `FileStream` has no `WriteLine` Member.

Comment: Oopps my bad.  I was thinking of certain wrappers.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use flush to save

```
logFileStream.Flush();
```

EDIT:

Close should also flush, but if it happens later it is possible that the buffer gets garbage collected

Comment: Doesn't Close() also flush the stream?

Comment: He didn t call it in the WriteLine, wasn t sure he ever did it.

Comment: Thank you! It gets saved, but another problem: There's no line breaking. All is in the same line in the text-document. But I used "\n": `byte[] textArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm:ss") + "] " + text + "\n");

            logFileStream.Write(textArray, 0, textArray.Length);
            logFileStream.Flush();`

Comment: @namespace if you are viewing it in notepad it does not recognise `\n` for line breaks you need to use `\r\n` or `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: @namespace use Environment.NewLine instead of \n

Comment: @namespace Your welcome, and use WriteLine instead of Write if you want new lines

Comment: Thanks all, \r\n solved my second problem.
@Maximc - "FileStream" has no WriteLine-Member-Function.

Comment: @namespace ah yes you are right streamwriter has a writeline not the FileStream, my bad anyway you got it fixed with \r\n